# Why can I not use my existed payment profile during sign up in google cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Why can I not use my existed payment profile during sign up in google cloud? It's displayed but unavailable.[image]

Comment: A good bet could be that you are in Russia, and Google does not allow private to use Cloud Platform for non business purposes (https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/resources/vat-overview?visit_id=1-636661488670358304-4268157747&rd=1) (Like the VAT issue in EU maybe?)

Comment: @MatteoRagni, thank you for your comment! Am I right understand that it's forbidden to use it on my own (have noticed the warning message in Russia's section)? For example for learning purposes?

Comment: For personal free use I think you should contact directly Customer Care, to see if there is a way to get a free quota. I really don't know if it is possible though...

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you duplicate your comment as the answer so I can mark it?

Comment: For sure! Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A good bet could be that you are in Russia, and Google does not allow private to use Cloud Platform for non business purposes.

Citing [Google Platform Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/resources/vat-overview?visit_id=1-636661488670358304-4268157747&rd=1):

> **Individual accounts in Russia**
>
> In Russia, Google Cloud Platform services can be used only for business purposes.
>
> Warning: If the sole purpose for which you want to use Google Cloud Platform services has no potential economic benefit you should discontinue your use of the service.

The last phrase makes me think that they discourage the usage of the service even for learning purposes, but I may be wrong. I think your only solution is contacting them directly to understand if there is some way to use only the free quota.